# basic question regarding $_GET with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Just playing around with ajax and php and I have a simple question.
These are the following relevant files.

**file.php**

```
<?php 
$bla = $_GET['pid'];
echo $bla;
?>
```

**HTML**

HTML Code of example site **URL:** somesite.com/blabla.php?pid=3

*(It contains a single button which when you click it is supposed to get the $_GET value from the URL which is 3)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Some Page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button class="fa fa-icon" onclick="someFunction()"></button>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
function someFunction(){
    $.ajax({
    method: 'POST', //I've tried 'GET' here too. doesnt make a difference
    url: "file.php", 
    success: function(result)
{
alert(result);}
});
}
</script>
```

As noted by the commenters below: I've also tried the following

```
<script>
function someFunction(){
    $.ajax({
    method: 'POST', //I've tried 'GET' here too. doesnt make a difference
    url: "file.php", 
    data: {pid: 3}, // added this line
    success: function(result)
{
alert(result);}
});
}
</script>
```

The alert is blank there is no 3 on it when the php file has echo $bla which is $_GET['pid'] and the pid in the url is = 3.

Can someone please explain why that is the case? I dont think I understand what is happening behind the scenes of the above codes to figure out why.

Please note that I'm not trying to solve a particular problem or anything just trying to understand why $_GET is not working in this very specific case.

Comment: File.php is executed. And you pass __no__ GET or POST parameters to this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not sending any data in the AJAX request, hence there's nothing for the PHP to read and send back. To fix this include a `data` property in the request which contains the `pid` key and the required value, for example:

```
function someFunction(){
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "file.php", 
    data: {
      pid: 3
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Note that I'm using `method: 'GET'` here, which is important as you're using `$_GET` in your PHP, so a `POST` request won't work. Also note that I'm using `console.log()` to debug the value. `alert()` shouldn't be used for debugging as it coerces data types.

Comment: Thanks it works. I just noticed that the method was POST but I had GET in the php file...

Comment: This should work, even if the OP claims in the question that it didn't work for him.

Comment: @Álvaro González  Yes it works now. (Got mixed up with POST and GET)